# Ruby on Rails - @user.create_session wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, this issue is getting me pull my hair out. I have this controller action, which creates user. But @user.create_session is never successful, even if @user.save was success.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.password_changed
    if @user.save
      session[:session] = @user.create_session
    end
```

The method in User model create_session is this

```
  def create_session
    if self.session.nil? or self.updated_at < 1.month.ago
        begin
            self.session = Crypto.new.salt(50)
        end while User.find_by_session(self.session).nil? == false
        self.save
      end
    return self.session
  end
```

Now if I do this, it creates session and everything works perfectly fine:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.password_changed
    session[:session] = @user.create_session
```

However I would prefer to generate session AFTER the registration, in case validation fails  or Im doing excess sql request + have meaningless cookie.

In IRB it works fine either way:

```
1.9.3-p374 :046 > @user = User.last
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 19, name: "Jkfsdkh", username: "hkjfaskh", password: "$2a$10$jAXv.FAmlZDi7xT.yeP/keri1p9pVnYygaCl0z7YMdpH...", email: "so@fs.cm", email_confirmed: false, salt: "Ju_ILOlqJnAXfc-z6gvO1cJUAguHwhtwBWJCGPDtxRw", session: "Pw0xu1b-gZfn1GEESZM1r2PAjzM4y-B5FFJ2vHKlkokpiM6gkyK...", ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-02-19 05:41:11", updated_at: "2013-02-19 05:41:48"> 
1.9.3-p374 :047 > @user.session = nil
 => nil 
1.9.3-p374 :048 > if @user.save
1.9.3-p374 :049?>   @user.create_session
1.9.3-p374 :050?>   end
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'me@janbirsa.cm' AND "users"."id" != 19) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'hkjfaskh' AND "users"."id" != 19) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "session" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2013-02-19 05:43:09.960854' WHERE "users"."id" = 19
   (2.8ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session" = '1_BezpY-5b4oaFhAOiR4zRuKb1mLVbU1MxmZs07dPY9LCKJ_t1XOXR82d8uXkCGjb0Y' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'me@janbirsa.cm' AND "users"."id" != 19) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'hkjfaskh' AND "users"."id" != 19) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "session" = '1_BezpY-5b4oaFhAOiR4zRuKb1mLVbU1MxmZs07dPY9LCKJ_t1XOXR82d8uXkCGjb0Y', "updated_at" = '2013-02-19 05:43:09.967159' WHERE "users"."id" = 19
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
 => "1_BezpY-5b4oaFhAOiR4zRuKb1mLVbU1MxmZs07dPY9LCKJ_t1XOXR82d8uXkCGjb0Y" 
1.9.3-p374 :051 > @user.session
 => "1_BezpY-5b4oaFhAOiR4zRuKb1mLVbU1MxmZs07dPY9LCKJ_t1XOXR82d8uXkCGjb0Y" 
1.9.3-p374 :052 >
```

Also when I am creating session from login controller it works fine too.

EDIT: Here, I re-created what controller does in irb.

```
1.9.3-p374 :001 > new = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, username: nil, password: nil, email: nil, email_confirmed: false, salt: nil, session: nil, ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p374 :002 > new.name = 'test'
 => "test" 
1.9.3-p374 :003 > new.username = 'test2'
 => "test2" 
1.9.3-p374 :004 > new.password = 'test123'
 => "test123" 
1.9.3-p374 :005 > new.email = 'test@t.cpm'
 => "test@t.cpm" 
1.9.3-p374 :006 > new.password_changed
 => true 
1.9.3-p374 :007 > if new.save
1.9.3-p374 :008?>   new.create_session
1.9.3-p374 :009?>   end
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@t.cpm' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'test2' LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password`
  SQL (4.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "email_confirmed", "ip", "name", "password", "salt", "session", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 20 Feb 2013 01:32:45 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test@t.cpm"], ["email_confirmed", false], ["ip", nil], ["name", "test"], ["password", "$2a$10$nrWM/es2D/1hrjaBVnNj3esBOEvRm9nILmTNiRvBJG00fUTRuPXui"], ["salt", "WRxgy_hoPPXo5v2QtoN47khXso3ZFfkSdDDB9uvH3P8"], ["session", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 20 Feb 2013 01:32:45 UTC +00:00], ["username", "test2"]]
   (3.8ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session" = 'KoBISJTarhdO1ZWFgn8HDk6zNts779QU0NUORIh84IRMFY4f6s4cV2w7BxgAa6pz3Ck' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'test@t.cpm' AND "users"."id" != 22) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'test2' AND "users"."id" != 22) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "session" = 'KoBISJTarhdO1ZWFgn8HDk6zNts779QU0NUORIh84IRMFY4f6s4cV2w7BxgAa6pz3Ck', "salt" = 'Q-4E-D7xNADTp9_qnSmAg5NATpHv1dWcUtvGExeUll8', "password" = '$2a$10$/aM541saVBBG/mHizdK05OBNfcLFVsMu.3rpnThKs5M71SBdC6aJ.', "updated_at" = '2013-02-20 01:32:45.659951' WHERE "users"."id" = 22
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
 => "KoBISJTarhdO1ZWFgn8HDk6zNts779QU0NUORIh84IRMFY4f6s4cV2w7BxgAa6pz3Ck" 
1.9.3-p374 :010 > new.session
 => "KoBISJTarhdO1ZWFgn8HDk6zNts779QU0NUORIh84IRMFY4f6s4cV2w7BxgAa6pz3Ck" 
1.9.3-p374 :011 >
```

Now I still can't figure out, why irb does fine and controller not. Its making me go nuts.

Comment: you should check what validation failed when you call self.save inside the create_session method.

Comment: Seems ok. I suggest you to use debugger gem to explore what happens in controller. And... please, do not write such code `begin end while ... .nil? == false` it's not the ruby way.

Comment: I started learning Ruby last week...what is a better way to write that end while?

Comment: Notice you didn't call `@user.password_changed` in your irb session before `.save`.

Comment: e.g. just `... while User.find_by_session(self.session)`

Comment: @user.password_changed is irrelevant, its just a setter for variable that triggers before_save filter that encrypts password.

Comment: laise that is much better. thanks.

Comment: is session is an attribute of user model ?

Comment: irb isn't testing the case of a newly created user - I'd investigate that more closely. Are you sure there aren't default values, before saves etc. that might result in the initial value of session being "" (the empty string) rather than nil?

Comment: No session is just column name. There is before save, which encrypts password. No default values on session. Its nil if done within if user.save and it has value when done plainly, however I know for sure that user.save is true.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've refactored my code to something that makes more sense. My registration controller is now as simple as:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.password_changed

    if @user.save 
        session[:session] = @user.session
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
    else
        render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

Session generation made more sense to be linked with password generation, therefore I merged them into one method, that is being called before save.

```
 before_save :encrypt_password, if: :password_changed?

  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = Crypto.new.salt
    self.password = Crypto.new(self.salt).bcrypt(self.password)
    begin
        self.session = Crypto.new.salt(50)
    end while User.find_by_session(self.session)
  end
```